# how to remove play minimized icon in a background video of a website

Tags: html, css

```css
.aboutvideo{
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
video{
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1; 
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop controls playsinline style="pointer-events: none;">
  <source src="./assets/sfx/Teaser.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

i used this to create background video but it shows play minimized icon when hovering mouse around. Is there any method to remove that.

Comment: You should not need `controls` on a _background_ video.

Comment: i tried removing that too, but still that appears

Comment: Can you clarify what you are referring to then? I have no idea what a "play minimized icon" is. (Perhaps something browser-specific?)

Comment: Have you removed the `controls` attribute as suggested in the first comment? It is causing the controls to show.